# How to create function in SQL Server?

Tags: database, sql-server-2014, sql-function

I need to create a function to check if an input string consists of UPPERCASE characters. This function should be defined with the following header.

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckStringOfUpperAlphaOK(@String varchar(MAX)) 
RETURNS varchar(6) 
AS
  ...
```

It should return "okay" if true and "not okay" if false. This is what I tried, but it does not return anything.

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckStringOfUpperAlphaOK (@String varchar(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(6)
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @KeepValues as varchar(50)
    Set @KeepValues = '%[^ ][A-Z]%'

    While PatIndex(@KeepValues collate Latin1_General_Bin, @Temp) > 0
        Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@KeepValues collate Latin1_General_Bin, @Temp) + 1, 0, ' ')

    RETURN @Temp
END
```

Comment: How many character in not okay?

Comment: Would you please explain what this function does. what do you mean of "string consists of UPPERCASE characters" ?

Comment: If the input being all uppercase is so important to the function of your app, would it not just be simpler to use the built in UPPER() function to make everything inputted uppercase anyway?

Comment: This function should check if there are any uppercase characters in an  input. and return "okay" if there are any. and return "not okay" if there arent any